# Why does Ruby expose symbols?

Tags: ruby, symbols

Why does Ruby expose symbols for explicit use? Isn't that the sort of optimisation that's usually handled by the interpreter/compiler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of the issue is that Ruby strings are mutable. Since every string Ruby allocates must be independent (it can't cache short/common ones), it's convenient to have a `Symbol` type to let the programmer have what are essentially immutable, memory-efficient strings.

Also, they share many characteristics with `enum`'s, but with less pain for the programmer.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby symbols are used in lieu of string constants in other similar languages. Besides the performance benefit, they can be used to semantically distinguish between string data and a more abstract symbol. Being syntactically different, they can clearly be distinguished in code.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Ruby symbols](http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-symbols/) post.

Comment: You may also want to look at http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol